# Safari is returning incorrect width using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

Here is the problematic part of my jQuery

```
var tickerWidth = 0;
var padding = 10;
firstList.find('li').each(function() {

            $(this).append(' &mdash;');
            tickerWidth += $(this).width() + padding;  

           $('body').prepend($(this).width() + '<br />');

        });
```

`firstList` is a variable that holds an `ul` element. When I run this in Firefox, I correctly get the widths calculated and printed to my page. However, in Safari, I get the width much narrower - about the width it would be had the `&mdash;` not been inserted... is this some sort of race condition?

Is there any way to combat this? Perhaps loop through first and insert the html entity, and then loop through again to calculate width?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I did loop through first, insert the html entity, and then do another loop, but the values are still incorrect...

I've also tried `outerWidth()` but it hasn't helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've got it to calculate it correctly, though it's a bit ugly.

Instead of `append()`ing the entity, I insert it like so

```
        $(this).html($(this).html() + ' &mdash;');
```

This works fine.

Comment: an odd bug to be sure. You might want to submit this behaviour to the jquery development mailing list

Comment: Go ahead and accept your own answer so that this question doesn't show up as *unanswered* in the site.

Comment: @ichiban - you must wait 48 hours before you can accept your own answer.